# Terraform | ignore_changes in dynamic block

Tags: terraform

I have a block `ignore_changes` and I want to make more elegant way to code it, for now my solution is:

```
    dynamic "container" {
         for_each                = var.settings
         content {
         image                 = "my_image"
    }
  }


  ignore_changes = [
       container.0.image,
       container.1.image
    ]
```

how can I take it in loop within ignore_changes block?

Comment: Where is the block `ignore_changes`? What is the complete TF code demonstrating your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a PR open for the same and it is currently not supprted

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24188

Alternatively, try this work around

```
containers = var.settings

 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [containers.*.image]
  }
```

or

```
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [settings.*.image]
  }
```

Comment: I tried that and got an Error: Invalid expressions `A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template expressions, etc are allowed here.`

Comment: can u try. ignore_changes = [settings.*.image]. or.  ignore_changes = [settings]

Comment: @MyITGURU Although `ignore_changes = [settings]` works, but it really ignores a lot of other nested aguments.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar Looks at the requirement to ignore all images but not entire  [settings], Thats not my suggestion.